# Using Thermal Epoxy vs Super Glue for Thermal Couple temperature measuring

Tags: microcontroller, temperature, thermal, thermocouple

Which practice is better for measuring the temperature if a MCU on a PCB with a thermocouple: Measuring on the case of the MCU with thermal epoxy attached to the thermal couple, or super glue?

I feel like with thermal epoxy, you will have an intermediate material that could slow down the recorded temperature on the thermalcouple because of the extra thermal resistance. With super glue, you will only need to fasten the thermal couple to the MCU, but you may not get a reliable connection. I wanted to get some input to understand what is the better practice.

Comment: I would use a clip, or kapton tape. I don't know why you think thermal mass would be an issue with epoxy but not superglue. Both epoxy and superglue are also really permanent.

Comment: Clip on, use thermal PASTE (heatsink compound).   Crazy glue is always a terrible choice, especially around electronics.  It emits gasses as it cures which can damage nearby stuff.  (Put a drop on a piece of glass and watch what happens).   Make sure the sensor TOUCHES the IC body, not just embedded in the goop.  "Less is more" is a good motto when using any kind of 'stuff' to conduct heat.  The goal is ONLY to fill the microscopic air gaps, not to smear it on like you're making a PBJ sandwich.

Comment: BTW, thermal paste is quite expensive. But you only need a vanishingly small amount in most cases.   Buy a $30 container, it'll be enough to last you your whole life most likely.

Comment: radical idea: have you tough about contactless infrared? for semiconductors is really useful. As for superglues you have some unknown thermal resistance in your thermal path

Comment: Superglue would be OK if you don't need to remove the thermo-couple, however then the product of choice would be a low bloom/low odor cyanoacrylate to reduce some of the potentially harmful effects... In your case, you would need to remove the probe undamaged and some kapton tape is what people would use ...

Comment: @KyleB Not such a great idea. Themal paste, like most glues and compounds, has a limited shelf life. After 5 or so years it will be all nasty and dried up. Only buy what you expect you can use within the next couple of years. I buy tiny little sachets that are usually plenty for one application. Only buy one of those syringes if you expect to be greasing up a dozen compenents at a time.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the cunductivity too much. It's an external sensor, presumably exposed to airflow. It's a substandard proxy for the actual die temperature, no matter how youl look at it. Just go for whatever holds better. Superglue is more likely to crack and degrade at high temperatures.